# Weblogic - Unable to find setter method for attribute

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I'm getting the exception in the title for custom JSP tags. The thing is, the setter method exists. We actually have 2-3 setter methods for each attribute. One that receives Object, one for String and one for the specified in the tag's tld (usually boolean).

This exception is not consistent. I am unable to predict when it will happen and no idea how it is fixed. I have the exact same application deployed on a server, with a page throwing this exception, yet this exact same page works fine when I run the application locally with Eclipse.

I once made a "fix" for this problem that occurred with some tag.
The tag has an attribute

```
Booelan someAttribute = "true"; // Or something like that, the actual code is at work
```

and the 3 setters are

```
public void setSomeAttribute(Object attr) { ... }
public void setSomeAttribute(String attr) { ... }
public void setSomeAttribute(Boolean attr) { ... } // The type of the attribute in the tld
```

For some reason it threw this exception, so I added a fourth setter

```
public void setsomeAttribute(Object attr) { ... }
```

And it fixed the problem! 
No other tag required this weird solution, the problem was fixed over redeployments and copying the code from the SVN repository and other not-permanent solutions.

I really have no idea what's causing this problem or how to investigate. 
I'd really appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have just one setter method? Why do you need these 3 setter methods?

If you code a setter method that accepts an Object, why are you coding a setter method for a String and another for a Boolean? You can handle all those cases in just one method:

```
setSomeAttribute(Object attr)
```

Comment: We had problems with that, it looked like it was required to create a setter that receives exactly the type specified in the tld. For cases when it was not in the tld, we added the String and the Object setters to cover all possibilities.